# Debian: xinit with startx always returns exit code 0

Tags: debian, systemd, exit-code

I am starting kiosk mode application (Electron based) with startx in systemd service. I need to stop service when application is exited with specified exit code. The user running service is not in group sudoers, so I can't stop service with systemctl.

The script which starts the application returns exit code of application, but startx always returned exit code 0.

How to propagate exit code in startx or xinit to provide the correct exit code from application?

Systemd service code:

```
[Unit]
Description="kiosk mode service"

[Service]
User=kiosk-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/kiosk
ExecStart=/home/kiosk-user/run_x.sh
Restart=on-failure
SuccessExitStatus=999
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

run_x.sh code:

```
#!/bin/bash

startx /home/kiosk/run_application.sh --
ret=$?
echo "run_x.sh returned ret: $ret"
exit $ret
```

run_application.sh code:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/kiosk/startelectron

ret=999

echo "run_application.sh returned ret code $ret"
exit $ret
```

log from service:

```
Nov 12 11:22:08 vendotel run_x.sh[3349]: run_application.sh returned ret code 999
Nov 12 11:22:09 vendotel run_x.sh[3312]: run_x.sh returned ret: 0
```

Comment: Though hacky, you could temporarily save the return code in a file.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about that.